# exception handling with StateT vs ReaderT IORef

Tags: haskell, monads, ioref

It seems a lot easier to maintain state through exceptions by holding on to an `IORef` than to try to use the State Monad. Below we have 2 alternative State Monads. One uses `StateT` and the other `ReaderT IORef`. The `ReaderT IORef` can easily run a final handler on the last known state.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Monad.State (MonadState, execStateT, modify, StateT)
import Control.Applicative (Applicative)
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class ( MonadIO, liftIO )
import Data.IORef
import Control.Exception.Base
import Control.Monad.Reader (MonadReader, runReaderT, ask, ReaderT)

type StateRef = IORef Int
newtype ReadIORef a = ReadIORef { unStIORef :: ReaderT StateRef IO a } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader StateRef)
newtype St a        = StM       { unSt      :: StateT Int IO a } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState Int)

eval :: St a -> Int -> IO Int
eval = execStateT . unSt

evalIORef :: ReadIORef a -> StateRef -> IO a
evalIORef = runReaderT . unStIORef

add1 :: St ()
add1 = modify (+ 1)

add1Error :: St ()
add1Error = do
  modify (+ 1)
  error "state modified"

add1IORef :: ReadIORef Int
add1IORef = do
  ioref <- ask
  liftIO $ do
    modifyIORef' ioref (+ 1)
    readIORef ioref

add1IORefError :: ReadIORef Int
add1IORefError = do
  ioref <- ask
  liftIO $ do
    modifyIORef' ioref (+ 1)
    void $ error "IORef modified"
    readIORef ioref

ignore :: IO a -> IO a
ignore action = catch action (\(_::SomeException) -> return $ error "ignoring exception")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  st <- newIORef 1
  resIO <- evalIORef add1IORef st >> evalIORef add1IORef st
  print resIO -- 3

  resSt <- eval add1 1 >>= eval add1
  print resSt -- 3

  stFinal <- newIORef 1
  void $ ignore $ finally (evalIORef add1IORefError stFinal) (evalIORef add1IORef stFinal)
  print =<< readIORef st -- 3

  -- how can the final handler function use the last state of the original?
  void $ ignore $ finally (eval add1Error 1) (eval add1 1)
  print "?"
```

So at the end of the main function, how can I run a final handler that has access to the last existing state of the State Monad even when an exception is thrown? Or is the `ReaderT IORef` optimal or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a way, but let me first explain recovering state from errors in terms of `ErrorT` and `StateT`, because I find that it illuminates the general case very well.

Let's first imagine the case where `ErrorT` is on the outside of `StateT`.  In other words:

```
m1 :: ErrorT e (StateT s m) r
```

If you unwrap both the `ErrorT` and `StateT` newtypes you get:

```
runErrorT m1
    :: StateT s m (Either e r)

runStateT (runErrorT m1)
    :: s -> m (Either e r, s)
```

The unwrapped type says that we recover the final state, even if we receive an error.  So just remember that `ErrorT` on the outside of `StateT` means we can recover from errors while still preserving the current state.

Now, let's switch the order:

```
m2  :: StateT s (ErrorT e m r)

runStateT m2
    :: s -> ErrorT e m (r, s)

runErrorT . runStateT m2
    :: s -> m (Either e (r, s))
```

This type tells a different story: we only recover the ending state if our computation succeeds.  So just remember that `ErrorT` on the inside of `StateT` means that we can't recover the state.

This might seem curious to somebody familiar with the `mtl`, which provides the following `MonadError` instance for `StateT`:

```
instance (MonadError e m) => MonadError e (StateT s m) where ...
```

How does `StateT` recover gracefully from errors after what I just said?  Well, it turns out that it **does not**.  If you write the following code:

```
(m :: StateT s (ErrorT e m) r) `catchError` f
```

... then if `m` uses `throwError`, `f` will begin from `m`'s initial state, **not** the state that `m` was at when it threw the error.

Okay, so now to answer your specific question.  Think of `IO` as having a built-in `ErrorT` layer by default.  This means that if you can't get rid of this `ErrorT` layer then it will always be inside your `StateT` and when it throws errors you won't be able to recover the current state.

Similarly, you can think of `IO` as having a built-in `StateT` layer by default that is below the `ErrorT` layer.  This layer conceptually holds the `IORef`s, and because it is "inside" the `ErrorT` layer it always survives errors and preserves `IORef` values.

This means that the only way you can use a `StateT` layer above the `IO` monad and have it survive an exception is to get rid of `IO`s `ErrorT` layer.  There is only one way to do this:

- Wrap every `IO` action in `tryIO`
- Mask asynchronous exceptions and only unmask them in the middle of `tryIO` statements.

My personal recommendation is to go the `IORef` route since there are some people who will not be happy about masking asynchronous exceptions outside of `tryIO` statements, because then you cannot interrupt pure computations.

Comment: good note about the asynch exceptions.  I didn't think of that.

Comment: @rampion Thanks!  :) I had to learn this the hard way while building `pipes-safe`.  Asynchronous exceptions screw up lots of things in very non-obvious ways.

Answer (score 1):

Are you throwing these exceptions, or is a library?

Because if it's the former, why not use an EitherT transformer to do the exception handling?

You just need to be careful of the order: `StateT s (EitherT e IO) a` won't let you see the final state if there's an error, but `EitherT e (StateT s IO) a` will.

```
StateT s (EitherT e IO) a ~ IO (Either e (s -> (a,s)))
EitherT e (StateT s IO) a ~ IO (s -> (Either e a, s))
```

If you're using a library that throws exceptions, and you want to maintain state then you'd need to capture the exceptions within the State monad, using `lift $ catch libraryCall exceptionHandler`.

If you try to catch the exception outside of the State monad, like you're doing here, then that's isomorphic to `StateT s (EitherT e IO) a`, as you're using the error capabilities within `IO` to do the catching.  The state is unavailable at that level.